# Why is this plane circling around the Lucknow airport every day?

Tags: airport, online-tracking

Saw this plane circling around Lucknow airport (LKO).
This is happening [every day](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/6e8002). Any idea what is happening?
[image: Flight path]

Comment: NATS UK 24: https://youtu.be/a8CQ29yWvZI?t=97

Answer (score 39):

That is a plane being used to train/practice landings.

It is without passengers and one of the pilots is training. There will also be another pilot on board, possibly two, providing support and checking that the trainee is performing their duties according to the manual.

Comment: Or maybe a test flight?

Comment: @DeepSpace being an airline, not a manufacturer, I see that as unlikely

Comment: I would guess that if someone were to look up the approach plates for LKO, they'd find that the flight path follows a standard approach, too.

Comment: @Federico I'm pretty sure that airlines do test flights a lot of times. After C-Checks/D-checks for examples.

Comment: @DeepSpace personally, I never heard of such a test flight having the pattern shown in the question.

Comment: If it is indeed a new pilot, when coming in for a landing, he'll hopefully be in luck now.

Comment: @Baldrickk Haha, wow, it took too long for me to see that. :)

Comment: @Baldrickk Landing isn't the problem.  It's leaving when you're out of... (oh, dear...)

Comment: @Federico, What does the track of a post-maintenance checkflight look like?

Comment: @MichaelHall: https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/making-sure-an-aircraft-is-ready-to-fly/?utm_campaign=website&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email and for normal testing: https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/interesting-patterns-on-flightradar24/?utm_campaign=website&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, Thanks, but I was being a little bit facetious with Federico...  Your links make the point that you can't really say that the track in the original question does, or does not, resemble a PMCF.

Comment: @MichaelHall I think that the second link makes exactly that point. "Other pattern work" is exactly what we have in the question vs "flight test" (post maintenance or not)

Comment: I don't understand your point.  And the second link looks more like a search grid than anything else.

Comment: @MichaelHall scroll down the page

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't scroll.  So, I think we agree... right?

Comment: @DeepSpace according to Wikipedia, aeronautics is a major industry in Lucknow.  So maybe it **is** some sort of test flight.

Answer (score 9):

I asked Lucknow Airport via their official twitter. Their response was, erm, terse.

> **Q:** *Why does Indigo flight 6E8002 circle Lucknow Airport every single day for an hour?*
>
> **@aailkoapt (LUCKNOW AIRPORT):** *Training Flight.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter - Mar 16](https://twitter.com/aailkoapt/status/1106822545414578176)</sup></sub>