# I live near an airport and this morning a plane was circling the town 6 times

Tags: circling-approach

I live near an airport and this morning a plane was circling the town 6 times  but still was landing for few seconds but flying away again . And this thing happens often in our small city .Any opinions?

Comment: We'll need more details to definitively answer this. What airport, what time, any details of the aircraft etc. See the linked questions in the answer below to get an oidea of what is needed.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like someone was doing a [touch-and-go landing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch-and-go_landing). This is usually done when learning to fly an aircraft, to be able to practice a number of landings in a short time window. If there is a flight school at your local airport, this might explain why it happens a lot.

See also:

- [Why do planes sometimes make a touch-and-go?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54765/why-do-planes-sometimes-make-a-touch-and-go)
- [Why is this commercial plane making this manoeuvre?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/93236/why-is-this-commercial-plane-making-this-manoeuvre)

Comment: No i don't have flight school my town it's very small because of tourism we have airport .plus was a commercial flight

Comment: Pilots of commercial jets (airliners) need practice too. A quiet airport has plenty of opportunity for touch& go landing practices.

Comment: That's right. In fact, near my hometown there is a small regional airport (albeit with a quite long runway, since it's a former military airport), where Lufthansa used to do their A380 trainings, which was quite a sight for that area.

Comment: @ΝικαΑντρεεα My home airport is busy, so all the flight schools take their students to nearby airports for practice. And how do you know it was a “commercial” flight? If you mean it was a jet, they need training/practice too, or it could be a test flight after major maintenance.